# traverse tree of different type of objects

Tags: java, object, tree

I have a tree that consists of different type of objects for example

```
   Tree
    |  \
  apple  cat
    |  \
  dog  grass
        |   \
       door something
```

For example I can access the object something using Tree.getApple().getGrass().getSomething() where on every getter I have to check if the node exists. The problem is that the structure I use is pretty big and I want to have a utility class to speed this up.

I want only given the name of the object to be able to extract it from the structure. For example to have a method to which after I give Something.class as an argument to traverse the structure, return the object if it exists and return null otherwise. (I cannot have multiple occurrences of one class in the structure, i.e. I can have only one apple object)

Is that possible? What can I use to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a visitor that traverses the three and implement the filter in the visitor.

Roughly:

```
    public class LeafSearching {

    private final Class typeToFind;

    private Object result;

    public LeafSearching(Class typeToFind) {
        this.typeToFind = typeToFind;
    }

    public void visit(Node node) {
        if (typeToFind.isAssignableFrom(node.getClass())){
            result = node;
            return;
        }

        for (Node child : node.getChildren()) {
            child.accept(this);
        }
    }
}

interface Node {

    boolean hasChildren();

    List<Node> getChildren();

    void accept(LeafSearching ls);
}

class Apple implements Node {
    //...
}

class Cat implements Node {
    // ...
}

class TreeRoot implements Node {

    private Apple apple;

    private Cat cat;

    public Apple getApple() {
        return apple;
    }

    public Cat getCat() {
        return cat;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasChildren() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        final List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>;

        if (getApple() != null) {
            children.add(this.apple);
        }

        if (getCat() != null) {
            children.add(this.cat);
        }

        return children;
    }

    public void accept(LeafSearching ls) {
        ls.visit(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I cannot change the structure. So I guess I'll have to use some kind of visitor. There's another problem, which is: I don't have functionality to get children of a node. The children are given as class attributes with setters and getters. So I guess the main problem is getting the children (I guess I have to do this using reflection?).

Comment: I enhanced the example. Please look at getChildren in TreeRoot. But you can also use reflection of course.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is  inheritance.

Make a class called tree node for all types of nodes. This will work as a super class. 
For all the actual types such as apple, grass or something other make own class extending the treenode class. and in the traversal method you can check the type of each node to find desired type of node using instanceof method.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do can be achieved in several different ways, as stated above; you can use inheritance, you can use the [visitor pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-visitor) (maybe if you are using Eclipse, you can use it the way Eclipse ASTVisitor works).

I would say you could also use interfaces that declares a method like getChild(name), to check for the name of the class you are searching for and loop over the tree.

Bottom line here is, in my oppinion, that you just have to choose the way you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are traversing that data, but [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) is the operator you need here while checking for a particular class. And then call the appropriate method.